# Transposing rows to column by row, not column (Microsoft Excel)

Tags: excel, transpose

## **The Issue**

I want to transpose data given in rows to columns.

### **The Problem**

The Excel Paste Special -> Transpose on the full dataset goes by rows instead of by column.

## Example

#### Data

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5  |
|---|---|---|---|----|
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
```

#### Desired Result

```
| 1  |
| 6  |
| 2  |
| 7  |
| 3  |
| 8  |
| 4  |
| 9  |
| 5  |
| 10 |
```

I'd like to automate this process, however, I'm not too familiar with VBA. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.
Enter the formula shown in A4 and fill down:

[image]

Comment: It works in some cases, but not in others. for example:
I have more than 2 rows in each column and it varies from column to column.

Comment: So, it works for the question you posted, but not for the details you didn't mention?

Comment: I gave an simplified example as to not confuse anyone else that came to this question looking for help. Unfortunately, this was an error on my part, not on yours.